# Is it possible to access the Models/Database Entries that are present in a different project? [DB names are same in settings]

Tags: django, django-models, django-database, django-2.2

I am working on 3 different Django Projects named **frontend,API,Backend**. I have successfully implemented a custom Admin Interface as Backend, A middle layer for API request/Response and a Front End for consuming those APi's [**without  using Python & Django**] (Only **HTML,CSS,Javascript, Jquery, ajax**)

Now the Problem is that I do not know a way to use all these together. Someone told me that these can be run at once like a single project. How can I access the DB present in the API project's Models to use in Backend and Front End?

Can providing the same DB name in API and Backend Solve the problem? How can I integrate my Backend to the API?

Comment: Why do you have 3 separate projects?

Comment: I am experimenting and Someone has asked me to do it specifically it in the first place. Can it be done?

Comment: Everything can be done :) I would suggest merging your backend and API projects since they will be using the same models and DB. Having them separate does not give you anything other than complexity

Comment: Under the DATABASE setting putting the same configuration should allow all three projects to access the same database. 

To interact with each other, First you need to find a way so that these services can talk to each other (API, Queue etc) after that these services should run on different servers (if you are running on local then run all three on different ports) and expose api or configure queues.

Comment: @bak2trak thanks bud. This is the exact thing I am doing for front End. But will it be a good Idea to use API in the backend ?

Comment: @IainShelvington thanksman but I am told lke this

Comment: @Deshwal Nope! It's not :) But as you are told to do it like this so this is the way (may be not api but better would be to implement a queue service [producer/ consumer] )